# Form submission to subdomain

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe

I have one register form on my domain.com that is sending form details to my subdomain.domain.com, so I loaded subdomain form as hidden iframe on main domain. Registration form is using security token so I need to get the value from iframe.

This is the iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://my.subodmain.com/register/" id="iframe" style="width:600px;height:600px;border:dotted 1px red" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

As the subdomain registration form its using security token I need to get that value too, i.e. 'value="7901a00fe1d3c05ad0bbe4a2edbe84cb"', this is how it looks on actual iframe/subdomain registration form :

```
 <input type="hidden" name="security_token" value="7901a00fe1d3c05ad0bbe4a2edbe84cb" />
```

The above line should be loaded right under this main domain line :

```
<input type="submit" name="send" form="login" class="send" value="Sign Up">
```

result should be like this on main domain :

```
<input type="submit" name="send" form="login" class="send" value="Sign Up">
<input type="hidden" name="security_token" value="7901a00fe1d3c05ad0bbe4a2edbe84cb" />
```

I tried this on main domain but failed :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

 var $currentIFrame = $('#iframe'); 

 $currentIFrame.contents().find("body #security_token").val("security_token");
   </script>
```

Anyone can help me with full jquery script to achieve what I need ? Maybe my whole iframe idea is wrong and data can be retrieved from subodmain ? , I would appreciate the correction. Thank you !

Comment: You're input field doesn't have the `id` security token, but `name` secturity token. So should be something like `$currentIFrame.contents().find("body input[name='security_token']").val("security_token");`

Comment: still failing , do you have skype ?